# Using JavaScript to add a JSON property value into a HTML element's attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I have some "img" properties within a JSON file, which have .jpg file paths as their values (e.g "images/image.jpg").

Im trying to add these values into the 'src' attribute of existing HTML elements, the following is what I have tried so far…

1. Creating text nodes from the JSON object, then trying to add those as the 'src' attribute values using the '.setAttribute()' method, which results in an object being added instead of the url path as a string.

   var img = document.createElement("img");
   var imgSrc = document.createTextNode(object);
   img.setAttribute(src, imgSrc);
2. Using the 'JSON.stringify()' method to convert the JSON values into strings and adding those as the img elements 'src' attribute values. This results in the src attribute being filled with the correct paths, but they are surrounded by %22, presumably representing the quotation marks that surround strings.

   var img = document.createElement("img");
   var imgSrc = JSON.stringify(object);
   img.setAttribute(src, imgSrc);

Any ideas on how I can achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the JSON object structure look like?

Comment: The question is really unclear. Are you sure you even have JSON? (Remember that JSON is a *textual* notation.) What does the JSON look like? How are you getting it? Have you already parsed it (your code above refers to a variable called `object`, which *suggests* that the JSON text has already been parsed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a JSON string that has already been parsed into a JavaScript object (or perhaps you're not using JSON at all, and your starting point is the object). You haven't told us what the JSON is or what the object structure is. In a comment below, you gave *part* of it:

```
"img": "_/images/image-one.jpg"
```

...but that would be invalid JSON just on its own. I'm going to assume the actual JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "img": "_/images/image-one.jpg"
}
```

...and that it's *already* been parsed, so we have an object referenced from the variable `object` that has a property, `img`, containing the URL for the image.

To use the `img` property from that object, you just refer to it:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = object.img;
```

Comment: The JSON string is the url of a image ("img": "_/images/image-one.jpg". Not sure if this is bad practice? (this is my first javascript/json project im working on). I get the following dev tools console error message 'GET http://localhost/~user/website/%22images/image-one.jpg%22 404 (Not Found)', which I guess is down to the %22's as the rest of the path is correct?

Comment: @dntz: I think I understand your question now. I've updated the answer.

Comment: sorry, reading your answer I now realise my question was unclear. I imagined the property would have to have something done to it, like when placing a property within a element it needs appending to a text node first. I presume 'img.src = object.img;' is equal to img.setAttribute("src", object.img);, which works perfectly, could you tell me what I need to research to learn the fundamentals behind the 'img.src = object.img;' statement. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @dntz: You're welcome! *"I presume 'img.src = object.img;' is equal to img.setAttribute("src", object.img);, which works perfectly"* Pretty much. `src` is a DOM property defined for `img` elements that *reflects* the value of its `src` attribute. There are a lot of handy reflected properties. *Most* of the time, the reflected property is equivalent to using the attribute, but sometimes there are differences. *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* For instance, if a link has an `href` attribute that's relative, the `href` property contains the *resolved* path whereas `getAttribute` gets the relative one ([example](http://jsbin.com/cumanefi/1)). Similarly, the `value` *property* on input elements gives you the current value, but the *attribute* gives you the attribute value in the markup ([example](http://jsbin.com/cumanefi/2)).

Comment: *"...could you tell me what I need to research to learn the fundamentals behind the 'img.src = object.img;' statement..."* A good book on JavaScript should do it. I liked *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* by Flanagan, but you have *lots* of choices.